# If error in after insert trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

Suppose I have two triggers for a table `X`: `after insert` and `before insert` triggers, and I'm trying to insert values in to table `X`.

If an error happened in `after insert` trigger while I am inserting values, what will happen to my insert values? Is it in my table or rollback?

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati: However, if the `INSERT` was conducted as part of a transaction that doesn't get committed as a result of the error... (admittedly that's slightly out of the question's scope, but a useful observation nonetheless).

Comment: Thanks for your replay AlpeshPrajapati ..

Comment: @eggyal : I know its late but thanks 'eggyal' ;-)